# SAM: How to convert custom grayscale mask to Meta's Segment Anything format?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Looking at Meta's Segment Anything model, it seems to accept a low-resolution input mask to further refine its results.

`mask_input (np.ndarray, optional): A low resolution mask input to the model, typically coming from a previous prediction iteration. Has form 1xHxW, where for SAM, H=W=256.`

However, their documentation doesn't provide any clear info on how to convert a custom grayscale / binary map to the format they support.

I don't want to re-use their logits but provide my own input. Can anyone help me understand how to use custom masks with SAM? How to achieve a conversion between grayscale to the logits needed by SAM?

I tried converting my mask with different approaches, similar to the one below - but they all ultimately failed.

```
def reference_mask_to_sam_mask(self, ref_mask: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        # Normalize the mask to [0, 1]
        ref_mask_norm = ref_mask / 255.0

        # Add a small constant to avoid extreme values
        epsilon = 1e-7
        ref_mask_norm = np.clip(ref_mask_norm, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)

        # Resize the mask to (256, 256)
        ref_mask_resized = resize(
            ref_mask_norm, (256, 256), mode="reflect", anti_aliasing=True
        )

        # Convert probabilities to logits
        ref_mask_logits = logit(ref_mask_resized)

        # Add an extra dimension to make the shape (1, 256, 256)
        sam_mask = ref_mask_logits[np.newaxis, :, :]

        return sam_mask
```

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a similar question there and it doesn't seem possible or desired to parse your own masks. You should take a previous mask from previous iteration and add a box or label to respecify the area to segment.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/issues/169

Edit: Sorry it was also you there! So maybe this comment could help redirect people to that issue over there?